# Having trouble installing AdminBundle

Tags: php, symfony, composer-php

I'm trying to install Admin Bundle but it doesn't work and I don't know why,
Help me please!

```
$ composer require sonata-project/admin-bundle

PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20131226/php_intl.dll' - dlopen(/usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20131226/php_intl.dll, 9): image not found in Unknown on line 0
 Using version ^3.20 for sonata-project/admin-bundle                 
./composer.json has been updated
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)                       
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - The requested package sonata-bundle/admin-bundle could not be found in any version, there may be a typo in the package name.
  Problem 2
    - Conclusion: remove jms/di-extra-bundle 1.5.x-dev
    - sonata-project/admin-bundle 3.20.0 conflicts with jms/di-extra-bundle[1.5.x-dev].
    - sonata-project/admin-bundle 3.20.1 conflicts with jms/di-extra-bundle[1.5.x-dev].
    - Installation request for jms/di-extra-bundle (locked at 1.5.x-dev, required as dev-master) -> satisfiable by jms/di-extra-bundle[1.5.x-dev].
    - Installation request for sonata-project/admin-bundle ^3.20 -> satisfiable by sonata-project/admin-bundle[3.20.0, 3.20.1].

Potential causes:
 - A typo in the package name
 - The package is not available in a stable-enough version according to your minimum-stability setting
   see <https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#minimum-stability> for more details.

Read <https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/troubleshooting.md> for further common problems.

Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.
```

There is my composer.json

```
{
    "name": "symfony/framework-standard-edition",
    "license": "MIT",
    "type": "project",
    "description": "The \"Symfony Standard Edition\" distribution",
    "autoload": {
        "psr-0": {
            "": "src/"
        }
    },
    "repositories": [

        {
            "type": "git",
            "url": "https://github.com/DEVCKS/CKS-USER.git"

        },
        {
            "type": "git",
            "url": "https://github.com/DEVCKS/CKS-CORE.git"
        }
    ],
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.3.3",
        "symfony/symfony": "2.4.*",
        "doctrine/orm": "~2.2,>=2.2.3",
        "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "~1.2",
        "stof/doctrine-extensions-bundle": "~1.1@dev",
        "beberlei/DoctrineExtensions": "*",
        "sonata-bundle/admin-bundle": "*",
        "twig/extensions": "~1.0",
        "symfony/assetic-bundle": "~2.3",
        "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "~2.3",
        "symfony/monolog-bundle": "~2.4",
        "sensio/distribution-bundle": "~2.3",
        "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "~3.0",
        "sensio/generator-bundle": "~2.3",
        "incenteev/composer-parameter-handler": "~2.0",
        "awstudio/core-bundle": "dev-master",
        "friendsofsymfony/user-bundle": "dev-master",
        "jms/security-extra-bundle": "dev-master",
        "knplabs/knp-paginator-bundle": "~2.4",
        "friendsofsymfony/jsrouting-bundle": "~1.1",
        "jms/serializer-bundle": "@stable",
        "jms/twig-js-bundle" : "dev-master",
        "jms/twig-js": "dev-master",
        "liuggio/excelbundle": "2.0",
        "raulfraile/ladybug-bundle": "~1.0",
        "jms/di-extra-bundle": "dev-master",
        "doctrine/migrations": "1.0.*@dev",
        "doctrine/doctrine-migrations-bundle": "2.1.*@dev",
        "fresh/doctrine-enum-bundle": "v2.5",
        "corley/maintenance-bundle": "^0.1.7"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "Incenteev\\ParameterHandler\\ScriptHandler::buildParameters",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "Incenteev\\ParameterHandler\\ScriptHandler::buildParameters",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile"
        ]
    },
    "config": {
        "bin-dir": "bin"
    },
    "extra": {
        "symfony-app-dir": "app",
        "symfony-web-dir": "web",
        "incenteev-parameters": {
            "file": "app/config/parameters.yml"
        },
        "branch-alias": {
            "dev-master": "2.4-dev"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What does your composer.json file look like? It looks like `sonata-bundle/admin-bundle` may be present in there (which would cause Problem 1)

Comment: Look at my post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The `"sonata-bundle/admin-bundle": "*",` line is present in your `composer.json` file, but that package does not exist (causing *Problem 1*). Remove it
2. `jms/di-extra-bundle` is required to be installed according to your `composer.json` file, but `sonata-project/admin-bundle` specifically disallows that package to be installed (see: [GH-4292](https://github.com/sonata-project/SonataAdminBundle/issues/4292)). It looks like, at this time, you'll need to choose either *AdminBundle* or *JMSDiExtraBundle* to use.